# How do I copy-paste from Excel with TAB?

Tags: microsoft-excel, tabs

Is there any way we can copy paste data with TAB in windows another program?

For ex if I copy 5 cells from excel and paste in windows another application, it paste on single place with SPACE.

I need it should be paste in different tabs not in single tab. Like TAB should be use automatically used once first cell data is pasted

CELL 1 
TAB 
CELL 2
TAB
CELL 3....

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue. If I copy text from adjacent cells in `Excel` and paste into Word, the texts are separated by `TAB` characters. The same if I paste into `Notepad++` or `Notepad`

Comment: But I need to paste those cells data in a software which is like a form. For example when we sign up in a website we need to fill a form so if I have some data multiple cells and have to fill a sign up form If I copy multiple cells and paste over there it will be paste in one place not in different tabs.

Comment: Ah, you did not say that in your question. Anyway, it is the duty of the other (unknown) program to separate the data based on the TAB characters that Excel uses between the texts of the adjacent cells. You need to contact the manufacturer of that other software.

Comment: Sorry for that!

We can not do this through Macro?

Comment: No, no way a macro could do this.

Comment: @SahilManuja, You mean to say copy 4 cell & paste in 4 text boxes on a Web Form,,, ?

Comment: A macro can do this, but it involves sendkeys. It can quickly go very bad, especially since you need to switch between two softwares

Comment: @RajeshS, Yes I mean this, Can you please let me know the code how can I do this with sendkeys?

I want to try this once..

But I do not want to that on a Website, I have to paste that data on a Windows software..

Comment: Check this link,,, https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107068/how-to-allow-excel-data-to-be-pasted-into-website-text-boxes